# How do I get the stock icon for MIUI apps?

Tags: miui

I want to change the icon of MX Player to the same as MiVideo, but where do I get the icon for MiVideo within MIUI os itself? I tried /data/system/customized_icons but IT isn't there.

Answer (score 1):

FIgured it out by looking around the system files. Apparently, it's stored in `/system/media/theme/default/` in the file called `icons` which is just a zip file without an extension. Simply extract `icons` and I got the stock icons I needed.